# Sort Distinct Merged Columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A + ' ' + B + ' ' + C AS 'ABC', D
FROM Table
ORDER BY A, B
```

This gives the following error message:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

I tried changing the ORDER By to this:

```
ORDER BY A, B, C 'ABC', D
```

And pretty much every variation there is of those possible combinations but the error remains.

So how can i get the distinct ABC and D first sorted by the A value, and after that the B value? (The C and D may remain unsorted and don't have to be Distinct seeing the ABC combination is already enough to indicate a unique value)

EDIT:

Alternatively, is it possible to remove duplicates based on Columns A AND B  without using DISTINCT?

Comment: You can't. The error message makes full sense. E.g. `'A X ' + 'C'` = `'A ' + 'X C'`, but you can't order by its components.

Comment: seems like ORDER BY 1 will do it...

Comment: @jarlh but why am i able to order by it;s components when it's not DISTINCT?

Comment: Without DISTINCT, no rows have been "merged", i.e. the A, B and C values still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brock's example of using "row_number() OVER" i thought of a way to do it myself using PARTISION BY.

```
WITH ordering AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D,
        row_number() OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY
                A,
                B,
                C
            ORDER BY 
                A,
                B,
                C
        ) AS order_num
    FROM
        Table       
)
SELECT A + ' ' + B + ' ' + C AS 'ABC', D
FROM ordering
WHERE order_num = 1
ORDER BY A, B, C
```

This way, instead of using DISTINCT i use *"row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY"* to give all records a number, with the duplicates getting an increased number. This allows me to filter on the order_num being 1 to remove all duplicates. This way i can simply order by the original 3 columns seeing Distinct is no longer a part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple letter words in each column, you will need to order using a window function in a derived table or CTE as shown below:

```
WITH ordering AS (
    SELECT A,
           B,
           C, 
           D,
           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY A,B,C,D) AS order_num
    FROM Table
)

SELECT DISTINCT A + ' ' + B + ' ' + C AS 'ABC', D
FROM ordering
ORDER BY order_num ASC
```

Edited: new approach based on the comment

Comment: It comes close, but the problem is when value A has two words with the first word also appearing standalone.

Comment: Makes sense, I updated my answer. This should work depending on the SQL syntax you use

Comment: It still gave me the same error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." but your code inspired me to construct the correct answer myself so thanks for that :) Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use concat for string concatenation

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(A , ' ' , B , ' ', C) AS ABC, D
FROM Table
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Still not a valid ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a group by?

```
SELECT (A + ' ' + B + ' ' + C) AS 'ABC', D
FROM Table
ORDER BY A, B
GROUP BY (A + ' ' + B + ' ' + C), D
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [WITH clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html):

```
with a AS (
  SELECT A, B, C, concat(A , ' ' , B, ' ', C) AS abc, D
FROM table1 order by A, B, C
)
select distinct abc FROM a ;
```

Comment: Won't that order the string as a full ABC string? (So if string A contains 2 words and the first word also appears without a second word it will be out of order)

Comment: @A.bakker Edited answer after your hint. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use single quotes to delimit column names!  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  If you had done this, your code would have just worked the first time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A + ' ' + B + ' ' + C AS ABC, D
FROM Table
ORDER BY ABC;
```

Comment: Sorting by A and then B is different from sorting ABC as one single string.

Comment: @A.bakker . . . That is true.  This is my guess on what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL>create table t (id int, c1 varchar(3), c2 varchar(3));
SQL>insert into t values (1,'AX','B');
SQL>insert into t values (2,'AB','D');
SQL>insert into t values (3,'A','XB');
SQL>select concat(c1,c2) from t order by c1, c2;    

======
AXB
ABD
AXB

                  3 rows found
```

You can see above that row 2 (`ABD`) is sorted after one `AXB` row, and before the other `AXB` row, as the `order by c1, c2` specifies.

When you do `SELECT DISTINCT`, these two `AXB` rows will become only one row - which represents two separate rows in the table, one which is sorted before the `ABD` row, and one after the `ABD` row.

You can't put the duplicate eliminated `AXB` both before and after `ABD`. That's why

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified.